# Missing the last letter off of referring keywords

Tags: php

I have some php code which collects the keywords used to get to my website from some javascript and stores them in to a database, this all works fine except it misses the last letter off of the end of the keyword string so for example if the keyword was example it would get exampl.

```
//Get keywords from reffering website
 function getReferalHost()
{
$ref = parse_url( $_GET['self'] );
$refer = $ref['host'];
return $refer;
}

function getKeywords()
{
$refer = str_replace( '%2520' , '+' , urlencode( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) );
$refer = str_replace( '%26' , '&', $refer );
$refer = str_replace( '%3D' , '=', $refer );
$host_ref = parse_url( $_GET['self'] );
$host = $host_ref['host'];

if(stristr($host,'google.'))
{
    //do google stuff
    $match = preg_match('/&q=([a-zA-Z0-9+-]+)/',$refer, $output);
    $querystring = $output[0];
    $rep = str_replace('&q=','',$querystring);
    $querystring = substr( $rep , 0 , ( strlen( $rep ) - 1 ) );
    $keywords = explode('+',$querystring);
    return $keywords;
}
elseif(stristr($host,'yahoo.'))
{
    //do yahoo stuff
    $match = preg_match('/p=([a-zA-Z0-9+-]+)/',$refer, $output);
    $querystring = $output[0];
    $rep = str_replace('p=','',$querystring);
    $querystring = substr( $rep , 0 , ( strlen( $rep ) - 1 ) );
    $keywords = explode('+',$querystring);
    return $keywords;

}
elseif( stristr($host,'msn.') or stristr($host,'bing.') or stristr($host, 'ask.com' ) )
{
    //do msn stuff
    $match = preg_match('/q=([a-zA-Z0-9+-]+)/',$refer, $output);
    $querystring = $output[0];
    $rep = str_replace('q=','',$querystring);
    $querystring = substr( $rep , 0 , ( strlen( $rep ) - 1 ) );
    $keywords = explode('+',$querystring);
    return $keywords;
}

}

define('DELIMITER' , '  ');
                     $request_uri = getReferalHost();
                     $keys = getKeywords();
                     $query_string = "";
                     foreach( $keys as $key ){
                     $query_string .= $key.DELIMITER;
                     }
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 0):

you have:

```
 $querystring = substr( $rep , 0 , ( strlen( $rep ) - 1 ) );
```

in all cases, have you tried to remove that line?

Comment: Ok i thought that had worked, it gave me back the last letter but what it also did was dump some of the variable in to the database table for example:  q=Youth

Comment: if you remove the line, you have to change `$keywords = explode('+',$querystring);` to `$keywords = explode('+',$rep);` as @MrCode said

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
$querystring = substr( $rep , 0 , ( strlen( $rep ) - 1 ) );
```

Then, change this line:

```
$keywords = explode('+',$querystring);
```

To:

```
$keywords = explode('+',$rep);
```